# How to replace whitespaces with dashes

Tags: php

My idea is to remove special characters and html codes and replace the whitespaces to dashes
let us doing it step by step

```
$text = "Hello world)<b> (*&^%$#@! it's me: and; love you.<p>";
```

now i'm want the output become `Hello-world-its-me-and-love-you`
I've tired this code for removal of special characters and html codes

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = "/<.+?>/";
$array[1] = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/";

$textout= preg_replace($array,"",$text);
```

Now the output will be like this `Hello world its me and love you`
so is there any way i can modify this code so that the text output become exact as i do needs `Hello-world-its-me-and-love-you`

~ thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably better off using `strip_tags` to get rid of the html tags for you, then use a regexp to remove all non alphanumeric (or non-space) characters. Then you can simply convert spaces to hyphens using `str_replace`. Note I also added a line to collapse multiple spaces to a single space, since that is what you did in your example. Otherwise you get `world--its-me` instead of `world-its-me`.

```
<?php    
    $text = "Hello world)<b> (*&^%$#@! it's me: and; love you.<p>";
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    $text = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/', '', $text);

    //this is if you want to collapse multiple spaces to one
    $text = str_replace ('  ', ' ', $text); 

    $text = str_replace (' ', '-', $text);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add

```
$textout = str_replace(' ', '-', $textout);
```

after your last line to replace the spaces with hypens.